# Partition resize error

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, partitioning, grub

I've decided to remove my old linux [/] partition and enlarge my Win7 partition, before install new linux distro. 
For first time in my experience something gone wrong
when I tried to resize (enlarge into free space) my Win7 Partition with kde partition tool under Linux Mint. 
Partition tool failed to do that, and now I have my Win7 part. as unknown with information:

Unable to detect file system! Possible reasons are:
 - The file system is damaged
 - The file system is unknown to GParted
 - There is no file system available (unformatted)
 - The device entry /dev/sdb2 is missing

Without any chences to boot into it or restore or read any data. 
I don't like to lost this partition. 
There is still grub on part table, but booting into grub rescue.

Please help:)
Lucas

Comment: Consider the following : - Post here your current HDD partition structure by either taking screenshot of **Partition Tool** or using **fdisk**. - Be more specific about where the location of Old Linux Partition and Windows 7 was before this incident? - While @RobJ suggested a very fine advise, you may, if that fails, would like to search for any log(s) which **Partition Tool** might have taken before making changes. It would be very useful if it contains the *Start* and *End* of the sectors of various partitions before this incident. We can use it to revert back.

Answer (score 0):

On another system, prepare a live CD containing TestDisk, and boot the problem system with it.  You should be able to use it to find and restore your partitions and partition table.